# Sonata admin bundle does not display the list of object in production mode on the host server

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm getting a problem with sonata that I don't understand at all:
in localhost I can run my application very fine without any problem but when I upload it on the remote server, I can only run it with the dev mode if I run it in the production mode it work fine but when I try to display the list of the objects, only some of them can be done but those who have many rows generate "500 page error" I don't understand at all I clear the cache so many time but still the same problem comes back

Comment: have you set the permissions for the app/cache app/log folders? 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

Comment: thank you for your help but it does not fix the problem I set the permission of these folders all to 777 but I'm not able to delete rows of some of my entities

Comment: ok try to edit the post and show some code of how entities are deleted.

Comment: I'm using the popular bundle sonata admin bundle and to delete entities, as you probably know it just execute it bach action ... not that it works perfectly in dev mod and event in prod when I'm on localhost but on the remote server, only dev mod is working perfectly when I try to delete objects in prod mode it still generate error 500 and this is what I don't understand

Comment: have you  deleted the cache of prod enviroment? $ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod

Comment: of course ! this would be the first thing to do in such situation

Comment: Often with these kind of problems you should empty your cache and install your assets in the production environment:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#d-clear-your-symfony-cache

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#e-dump-your-assetic-assets

Also when you get a 500 it is important to check your apache and php logs as well as your symfony2 logs in /app/logs/prod.log for any errors.